# Workflow History in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created OOB approval workflow in sharepoint 2010.i want to add workflow history list in my webpart page.so i search in my list and libraries webpart that list not showing..i dont have access for sharepoint designer.

I can visible that list using this link:

http://yoursite/Lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx

Can anyone have the solution for this?

Comment: it's a hidden list. By general you cannot show it without changing the hidden flag. See also https://nauzadk.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/showing-workflow-history-along-with-a-document-set-listitem/

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Just like Celophysis said, you will need to edit the properties in SPD to use it directly as a list view web part.

As a workaround, you can add a page viewer web part to show the workflow history page. Still you can view the list items. 
https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010-web-part-series-page-viewer-web-part/